# getting following warning in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to remove the warnings,But when i try to run the code following warnings are generated,Can anyone help me

```
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:489)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:592)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1878)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1805)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1347)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1280)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-19 12:17:16.681: WARN/ImageView(4551):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks you've deleted a resource file and did not clean your project, so the mention of this resource in R file remained. Try cleaning your project.

Comment: @egor i have cleaned the project,,,,,the code is very large,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to grab a resource with the same value as WHITE in ARGB! Check for any lines of code where you are trying to directly grab a colour value as a resource (in this case 0xFFFFFFFF) where it should be referenced as R.color.[your-colour]. I'm guessing this issue is most likely in a piece of code that tries to set the background of a view (receiving an int and hence looking for a resource).

Comment: Add 0xFFFFFFFF as R.color.white and use that as the resource identifier.
Not sure about this but it looks like you've set the source of an ImageView as white which is strange. You should look at the code.

Comment: Never edit the R.java file, it is auto-generated. The problem is you are *LOOKING* for 0xFFFFFFFF somewhere in the code and that doesn't exist. Coincidentally 0xFFFFFFFF is also white, so you were trying to set something to white in the wrong place (or wrong way). I can't really help much further.

Comment: i agree with your point,now 0xFFFFFFFF  is not available in my code,,,so what should i do?

Comment: the value is -1 and it's not a color, it's a resource id, somewhere in the code there is a reference to resource id -1 that some api may return as not found